# Specify a single scss file in compass config.rb

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, web-deployment, gruntjs

I working on a deployment process for a HTML5 app. I'm using compass and SCSS to do styling and I have a config.rb in the root of my project dir to configure compass. I have an app.scss file that has a handful of imports at the top to import the other files in the correct order.

```
@import "definitions";
@import "common";

// global stuff
@import "modal";

// tabs
@import "login";
@import "summary";
@import "profile";
// etc.....
```

It seems though that I am unable to specify that app.scss file in the config.rb, it only has a **sass_dir** option which causes compass to try and compile each file. This breaks because, for instance, login.scss doesn't import definitions.scss and breaks if a variable from there is referenced. app.scss needs to be the only file compiled since only it knows about all of the other files

Is this possible? Also I'm unable specify command line args because eventually this will all be done through grunt and the grunt-compass plugin, so I need everything to be in config.rb

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not 100% certain this is the issue.. But..

I am assuming you are watching a directory when compiling. If so the files that you don't want to compile should start with an underscore.

For example...

**_myFile.scss**